# How to get location updates using location setting dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to implement google maps kind of functionality in my app where when app starts then location setting dialog shows if location is not active.When user clicks on **OK** button it should fetch users current location.

What I have done so far is it shows location dialog when location is not active and if I click **Ok** then it do not ask for permission to fetch location and when I click **No,Thanks**.It shows no action when I click any of these two buttons.

What I want:

1) When I click **Ok** it should ask for permission to fetch users location 
   and fetch current location.

2) When I click **No,thanks** it should show toast to describe why it is necessary to active location.

Here is my code:

I am implementing in fragment

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

 GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 LocationRequest locationRequest;
 private static final int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_CODE = 3310;
 private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 555;

 public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor

      @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    return view;

   }

       @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(mGoogleApiClient == null){

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
   }

   @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(mGoogleApiClient != null){

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

        settingsRequest();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

   }

   private void settingsRequest(){

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

final PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

  @Override
  public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {

     Status status = result.getStatus();
     switch (status.getStatusCode()){

          case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

             if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

           // check if the device has OS Marshmellow or greater than
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_CODE);

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                        }
                        else {

                        }

           }
           break:

           case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
          }        
         }
      });
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

  switch (requestCode){

     case 3310:

           if(grantResults.length > 0){

             for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++){

               if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                      }
                   else if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                   }
                   else {

                       getActivity().finish();
                   }
           }
         }
       }

  return;
   }

  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   switch(requestCode){

        case REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR:

            switch(resultCode){

               case Activity.RESULT_OK:
               break;

               case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
               break; 

             }

        break; 
    }
   }
 }
```

Please let me know what I did wrong or need to add anything in above code.

**THANKS**

Comment: You want to this type of dialog. [this](http://prntscr.com/ni917q)

Comment: Yes exactly , I am getting this but when I click OK it switch on the location but permission dialog is not showing ad No,thanks button is also not working.

Comment: Please check my answer. I just open that dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code: You can helpful my answer

> Gradle

```
implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
```

> In your Home Fragment:

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private Location locationData;

    private static final long TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION = 1000 * 5; // 1 Minute
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 5000;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);


        TedPermission.with(getActivity())
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .check();


        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION)    // 3 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }

    PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                locationChecker(mGoogleApiClient, getActivity());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }


        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                locationData = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            }
        }, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && getActivity() instanceof Activity) {
            try {
                Activity activity = (Activity) getActivity();
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

    public void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(activity, 1000);

                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.w("==>UpdateLocation<==", "" + String.format("%.6f", location.getLatitude()) + "," + String.format("%.6f", location.getLongitude()));
        locationData = location;


    }
}
```

> Output

You can get location in object `locationData`

Comment: but how can I get the current location and what  about permission dialog after clicking OK button.

Comment: Ok So you need to service for get location. if you want get current location in service class then i will edit my answer?

Comment: Yes bro I want complete solution please and what about after user clicks No,thanks button.

Comment: @Digvijay, I updated my answer with get update location.

Comment: And user click on `No,thanks` button then Can not `ON` GPS location

Comment: where is the code for No,thanks and is it TedPermission.with(getActivity()).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192566/discussion-between-nikunj-sorathiya-and-digvijay).